# Why HDMI shows more clear fonts comparing DisplayPort

Tags: hdmi, displayport, font-smoothing

I have 2 identical 4k Monitor (Philips 276E8V). One of them is connected to my Pc using DisplayPort and the other is HDMI 2.0

I thought DisplayPort is newer technology so I expected better quality on DisplayPort, but I noticed the one which is connected using HDMI, shows more clear and more crisp fonts.

Does this make sense? or something is wrong with me graphic setting?

I am using Windows 10 and AMD Radeon 7770

Comment: HDMI = __High-Definition__ Multimedia Interface whereas DisplayPort is not HD.

Comment: Are you saying HDMI is the better technology?

Comment: I'm not saying that, High-Definition is what it is. High-Def. DislplayPort is another type of VGA port, that is all. Just like VGA vs. Super-VGA. "HDMI vs. DisplayPort" http://www.diffen.com/difference/HDMI_vs_DisplayPort

Comment: My bad, DisplayPort __is__ also High-Def.

Comment: What resolutions are you using? Have you tried resetting both displays to factory settings? Have you tuned ClearType in the past?

Comment: @gronostaj I noticed that n different resolutions. In lower resolution the different is more noticeable

Comment: @gronostaj I also tried to set up clear type

Comment: "Does this make sense?" No. On identical monitors I would expect identical quality.  Three things to check: 1) Swap cables to the displays (to rule out that it is a display and not anything else).  2) Are all driver settings the same?  3. You mention win10. I have seen poor (fuzzy) displays when scaling. A log/off and log back in (or a reboot) would fix that.

Comment: @Hennes, good hints. I swapped the cables and got the same result. so seems some setting is different. I see too many factors here. different cable, different refresh rate and bit depth. So I'm confused

Comment: It's a setting somewhere. Many monitors can use filters, some monitors scale automatically under certain conditions. Check all settings on both monitors, compare. Make sure you have the same resolution on the PC side on both monitors.